# Angular 6 pass value from one service to another?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service

I'm trying to use latitude and longitude from the geolocation service in my list service. Unfortunately this keeps returning as undefined. Not really sure what the issue could be.

list.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable, Subject, asapScheduler, pipe, of, from, interval, merge, fromEvent, SubscriptionLike, PartialObserver } from 'rxjs';
import { List } from '../models/list.model';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { GeolocationService } from '../services/geolocation.service';

@Injectable()
export class ListService {

    constructor(private http: Http, private geoServ: GeolocationService) { }

    getLongitude() {
        this.geoServ.getLongitude().subscribe((longitude) => {
            console.log(longitude)
        });
    }

    private serverApi = 'http://localhost:3000';



    public getAllLists(): Observable<List[]> {

        const URI = `${this.serverApi}/yelp/${longitude}/${latitude}`;

        return this.http.get(URI)
            .pipe(map(res => res.json()))
            .pipe(map(res => <List[]>res.businesses));


    }
}
```

geolocation.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GeolocationService {

  constructor() { }

  getGeoLocation() {
    console.log('Geolocation working!');
    const options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0
    };
    const success = (pos) => {
      const crd = pos.coords;
      console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
      console.log(`Longitude : ${crd.longitude}`);
    };
    const error = (err) => {
      console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
  }


  getLongitude() {
    console.log('Geolocation working!');
    const options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0
    };
    const success = (pos) => {
      const crd = pos.coords;
      console.log(`Longitude : ${crd.longitude}`);
      const longitude = crd.longitude;
      return longitude;
    };
    const error = (err) => {
      console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
  }
}
```

thank you for taking the time to look at this. And I appreciate the further help on my additional question below. text text text text won't let me post until I add more details text text text text.

Comment: I think your syntax in GeolocationService is wrong. You need to subscribe to getCurrentPositions' Observable , don't you? where else should "pos" come from?

Comment: i'm not sure that's the issue is it? 
I'm able to execute :
      console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
      console.log(`Longitude : ${crd.longitude}`);
and see that logged in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything from your methods. You should use a `return` statement. You also need to use either a callback function a promise or a observable. I'll give you a observable example:

```
getLongitude() {
  this.geoServ.getLongitude().subscribe((longitude) => {
    console.log(longitude)
  });
}
```

And change your `getLongitude`:

```
getLongitude() {
  return new Observable((observer) => {
    console.log('Geolocation working!');
    const options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0
    };
    const success = (pos) => {
      const crd = pos.coords;
      console.log(`Longitude : ${crd.longitude}`);
      const longitude = crd.longitude;
      observer.next(longitude);
      observer.complete();
    };
    const error = (err) => {
      console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
      observer.error(err);
      observer.complete();
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
  });  
}
```

If you want to get the longitude and latitude in your getAllList method you can use the `mergeMap` operator:

```
public getAllLists(): Observable<List[]> {
  return this.geoServ.getGeoLocation().pipe(
    mergeMap(({ latitude, longitude}) => 
      this.http.get(`${this.serverApi}/yelp/${longitude}/${latitude}`)
    ),
    map(res => res.businesses)
  );
}
```

I'm using the `HttpClient` here. This is the 'new' http module from angular. It's advised to use this one instead of the old one. It also automatically does the `json()` call for you.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate that! I would upvote but i'm not able to until I get 5 more reputation.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind?

what if i'm trying to include the values in the list service URI ( i added the rest of the code to list.service.ts above)

Comment: @JaimeMoncayo I've updated my answer to what I think you mean. Make sure though to change the `getGeoLocation` to return an observable with an object containing latitude and longitude

Comment: so got a small issue with your code that figure you could solve it no problem. I opened a new question so you can get credit for another
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52010000/angular-type-issues