# Angular RxJS mergeMap types

Tags: angular, typescript, http

Trying to pull the longitude and latitude from a geo location service into `list.service` using `http.get` request URL.

First issue:

> businesses Property 'businesses' does not exist on type '{}'

Appreciate the help on this issue and the time

`list.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { List } from '../models/list.model';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { GeolocationService } from '../services/geolocation.service';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ListService {
    private serverApi = 'http://localhost:3000';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private geoServ: GeolocationService) { }

    public getAllLists(): Observable<List[]> {
        return this.geoServ.getGeoLocation().pipe(
          mergeMap<{businesses: List[]}>(({ latitude, longitude }) =>             
            this.http.get(`${this.serverApi}/yelp/${longitude}/${latitude}`).pipe(
            )
          ),
          map(res => res.businesses));
    }
}
```

`geolocation.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject, asapScheduler, pipe, of, from, interval, merge, fromEvent, SubscriptionLike, PartialObserver } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GeolocationService {

  constructor() { }

  getGeoLocation() {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      console.log('Geolocation working!');
      const options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 0
      };
      const success = (pos) => {
        const crd = pos.coords;
        console.log(`Longitude : ${crd.longitude}`);
        const location = {
          "latitude" : crd.longitude,
          "longitude": crd.longitude
        };
        observer.next(location);
        observer.complete();
      };
      const error = (err) => {
        console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
        observer.error(err);
        observer.complete();
      };
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
    });  
  }
}
```

`list.model.ts`:

```
export interface List {
    id: string;
    name?: string;
    rating?: number;
    review_count?: number;
    url?: string;
    location: string;
    display_name?: string;
    image_url?: string;
    is_closed?: boolean;
}
```

Added `model.ts` to help clarify

Comment: `getGeoLocation` doesn't return anything, so you need to return your observable

Comment: thank you that fixed the pipe issue still have have an issue with the businesses

Comment: Try ```this.http.get<any>(`${this.serverApi}/yelp/${longitude}/${latitude}`)``` in  list.service.ts, (or if you have an interface for the response type, use that instead of `any`)

Comment: return this.geoServ.getGeoLocation().pipe(

            mergeMap(({ latitude, longitude }) =>

            this.http.get<List[]>(`${this.serverApi}/yelp/${longitude}/${latitude}`)
            ),
            map(res => res.businesses)

I get an error still with businesses and <List[]> says expected 0 type arguments but got 1.

Comment: From copying / pasting the code above, I can see a few errors, but `List[]` won't have a `businesses` property (though an individuall `List` might, how should it behave with that in mind?

Comment: yelp passes 
{  
   "businesses":[  ],
   "total":3000,
   "region":{  
      "center":{  
         "longitude": xxxx,
         "latitude": xxxx
      }
   }
}
and the businesses array contains the 3000 businesses and their details

Comment: I've added an answer below that should work then.

Comment: @JaimeMoncayo I'm glad that you found the solution, but please - edit the question title because it's too broad. Make it more specific for your case in order to help search engines to show your question in the results correctly. Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code says that your GET returns a `List[]`, but an array wont have a `businesses` property, which is why it's complaining. You can use:

```
  public getAllLists(): Observable<List[]> {
    return this.geoServ.getGeoLocation().pipe(
      mergeMap(({ latitude, longitude }) =>
        this.http.get<any>(`${this.serverApi}/yelp/${longitude}/${latitude}`)
      ),
      map(res => res.businesses));
  }
```

This will compile, but if the response really is an array, the `Observable` may end up emitting `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are still using the old angular http client. This doesn't work well with typings either. To fix the typing add a type object to the `mergeMap` generic parameter

```
public getAllLists(): Observable<List[]> {
  return this.geoServ.getGeoLocation().pipe(
    mergeMap<{latitude: string, longitude: string}, {businesses: List[]}>(({ latitude, longitude }) =>             
      this.http.get(`${this.serverApi}/yelp/${longitude}/${latitude}`).pipe(
        map(res => res.json()), // remove after updating to new http client
      )
    ),
    map(res => res.businesses));
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that I updated it now and the code above! 
With the type object i get the errors:

ERROR in src/app/services/list.service.ts(19,11): error TS2558: Expected 2-3 typ
e arguments, but got 1.
src/app/services/list.service.ts(23,26): error TS2339: Property 'businesses' doe
s not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: @JaimeMoncayo I've updated my answer. I forgot that mergeMap has two generic types. It's better not to use `any` to maintain type safety